# When the same Maven CLI option is specified twice but with different values, which value is picked up by Maven?

Tags: maven, command-line-interface, maven-3

When I specify the same Maven CLI option multiple times with different values, which value is picked up by Maven?

For example, let's say I have

```
mvn -T 1 -T 4 -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skip=false install
```

Will the Maven build be executed with 1 or with 4 threads? Will the tests be executed or no?

Is there a guaranteed mechanism in Maven for picking up CLI option values?

Comment: Whatever you find out here, if it is not explicitly documented it is subject to change and usually when it is most inconvenient to you.  Don’t rely on it.

Comment: ..for maven (apache CLI) arguments (https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/CLIManager.java), i'd assume 1st wins, for "-D" properties, seems last wins(https://stackoverflow.com/q/10956676/592355)...so, my guess: `T=1` and `skip.test=false` :)

Comment: Have you checked which one will be picked up?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I think your comment is the answer. If you add it as an answer, I can mark it as the correct one.